# Word count by LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I need to count word by LINQ. Here is the code i use to count words in long string array but this not very efficient:

```
public static int WordCount(string haystack, string needle)
{
    if (needle == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    string[] source = haystack.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',', '*', '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var matchQuery = from word in source
        where word.ToLowerInvariant() == needle.ToLowerInvariant()
        select word;
    int count=matchQuery.Count();
    return count;
}
```

Suppose i have a string like this:

```
Geo Prism GEO 1995 GEO* - ABS #16213899 HGEO-
```

If i try to find GEO in the above sentence, my routine doesn't return the right count: I'd expect **4**.
What's wrong with my routine ?

Comment: Random note: I usually find `".?! ;:,*-".ToCharArray()` easier to read and type than an endless list of `char` literals.

Comment: "then my routine not being able give count the way i want." --- what *does* it do then?

Comment: Also, I count **3** "GEO" using the delimiters you've used. "HGEO" wouldn't count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have it as one-liner with LINQ:

```
void Main()
{
    string data = "Geo Prism GEO 1995 GEO* - ABS #16213899 HGEO-";
    var target = "GEO";
    var count = data.Select((c, i) => data.Substring(i)).Count(sub => sub.ToUpper().StartsWith(target));
    Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());
}
```

---

**Result:**

```
4
```

Comment: LINQ, like Bluetooth, makes everything better.

Comment: +1 for one-lining in Linq, but I'm not a massive fan of how this reads.

Comment: thanks ur code works.i started learning linq....so i am very weak in linq.i need bit explanation for ur linq code. what will be stored in (c,i) and what will be stored in sub. why u use here StartsWith(). this find any word starting with that word. how StartWith() works when any word start with "H" like HGEO-. please clear ur linq query in detail how it works.

Comment: Line breaks increase the readability. @Thomas: `String` inherits `IEnumerable<Char>`, hence you can use LINQ on it, so `Select((c, i)` [projects the `Char` and the index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) of the char in the string. [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) allows to pass the index, hence it iterates every possible consecutive substring in the string. [`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count) counts the (uppercase)substrings which start with the word to find.

Comment: sorry ur link not work in my scenario after test it. here is the code     string data = "Geo Prism GEO 1995 GEO* - ABS #16213899 HGEO-";
 var target = "Geo";
 var count = data.Select((c, i) => data.Substring(i)).Count(sub => sub.ToUpper().StartsWith(target));
 Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());

Comment: just use `var target = "GEO"` or change `sub.ToUpper().StartsWith(target)` to `sub.ToUpper().StartsWith(target.ToUpper())`

Answer (score 5):

Your code I think is almost right, but the reason you don't get 4 is because you need to do an "Contains" check since the last Geo is part of hgeo (assuming you meant to get 4, and not 3)

```
var matchQuery = from word in source
    where word.ToLowerInvariant.Contains(needle.ToLowerInvariant())
    select word;
```

Also, you might find it gives you better mileage to split your text with:

```
Regex.Split(haystack, @"\W+")
```

Which would split your text into a bunch of words, ignoring any grammar (untested, but I think should work)